# How to prevent video from getting messed up when concatenating via moviepy with method set to chain?

Tags: python, moviepy

I have a few clips that I want to combine to one video. Here's the code for that:

```
final = concatenate_videoclips(clips, "chain")
final.write_videofile("output-chain.mp4")
```

However, the output file is a bit messed up. The first clip was merged fine, but from the second clip onwards, the video is fully messed up, but the audio is intact. The video is not even visible properly. This doesn't happen if I set method to `compose` though. How can I fix this issue without setting method to compose?